# Shebang: History and Purpose

Tags: executable, shebang

I have few questions about the magic number `#!`, the shebang.
I read that it was introduced by Dennis Ritchie in the 70s as a way to see a script as an executable file.
I don't understand, why it was introduced. What brought him to introduce it? What did he like?
The second thing I don't understand is: why do I need to declare the script as an executable? I mean why do I have to do `chmod +x myscript`?
I think in the following way, once I put the string `#! myinterpter` then when I will make `./myscript` the OS will take this file, it will see that it contains the shebang and then it will call the appropriate interpreter. So why do I need to use `chmod +x`? Why does the OS (unix, linux) need me to make my script executable?

Comment: I can't comment about the history and purpose of #!, but chmod is granting permission to execute. I wouldn't say that chmod +x is actually "making it executable". I would categorize chmod +x as "allowing the file to be executed". You can do more fine tuning with permissions as well. chmod can tell the OS "only the owner of this file can execute it" or "users in the assigned group can execute this file". chmod +x is a short-hand (that I've actually never used, go figure).

Comment: Keep in mind you can have binary executables (for example, ELF binaries) that don't have the executable flag, the kernel doesn't know it can execute them.  The executable bit tells the kernel to look at the first bytes to see what *kind* of executable it is.  The shebang tells the kernel its a shell script.

Comment: Everything you want to know about `#!` is at http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/

Comment: Everything you want to know about `#!` is in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Comment: The shebang is for telling the program loader how to run the script. The `chmod` is for telling the OS that the script should be allowed to be executed by users. They are not related.

Comment: As to purpose, one purpose was to add a magic number to shell scripts. If you use the `file` or `magic` commands to determine what type of file is being examined (results could be piped through filter to find group), then the `#!` works as a two byte `magic number`.
Try `file /bin/* |grep shell` as an example.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Dennis Ritchie, sadly, is no longer with us so we can't expect to know what he was thinking, or what he liked about the shebang...